# Could not load assembly in NUnit

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, json.net

Seems like this should be a common problem that I expected to find an answer to via a quick Google search, but alas I cannot seem to find the answer.

I am writing a Unit Test using NUnit in C# for a method that relies on a third party library, Newtonsoft.Json to be specific.

When I attempt to call that method from my unit test I receive the all to common

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference" exception.

Both the unit test and the application are using the exact same newtonsoft library and the dll is set to copy local in both projects.

Seems like I am missing something super obvious but I can't seem to overcome this issue.

Comment: What runner are you using?

Comment: Assuming you mean test running, NUnit

Comment: There were an issue with .NET Framework versioning and targeting in NUnit Test Runner.

Comment: I'd try alternative runners first (TestDriven.NET, Resharper)

Comment: "The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference" Indicates that it can find the DLL, but there is a version mismatch between the assembly and what's in your project's manifest. Can you verify in windows explorer that the DLL's version really is 4.5.0.0?

Comment: Problem is we are using NUnit across the board, is the iisue simply that NUnit cannot handle this particular use case, that seems strange.

Comment: I'd also be curious to see if there's more than one version of this assembly in your gac -- perhaps NUnit is defaulting to a different version.

Comment: Unbelievable, the directory that contained our dll for Newtonsoft was had two versions. Whomever created the unit test project used the older of the two version product version of the dll is 4.5.11.15520in in the target app while the product version of the dll in the unit test app was 4.0.7.14524. Basically the answer was starring me right in the face based on the exception that was thrown. Thank you all for your help.  @ReacherGilt you might as well turn your comment into the answer so I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference" Indicates that it can find the DLL, but there is a version mismatch between the assembly and what's in your project's manifest. Can you verify in windows explorer that the DLL's version really is 4.5.0.0?

I'd also be curious to see if there's more than one version of this assembly in your GAC -- perhaps NUnit is defaulting to a different version.